# Matlab graph linetype

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, linestyle

I wrote the code below to plot 3 normal distributions with diferent line styles.

```
x = 20:0.0001:30;
m1 = 30;
s1 = 5;
pdfNormal_1 = normpdf(x, m1, s1);
m2 = 15;
s2 = 2;
pdfNormal_2 = normpdf(x, m2, s2);
m3 = 18;
s3 = 3;
pdfNormal_3 = normpdf(x, m3, s3);
set(gcf,'color','w');

g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
% set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
% set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
% set(g(3),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
set(gca,'Fontsize',12,'Fontname','euclid')
xlabel(' ') %título eixo xx
hold off;

%plot(x, pdfNormal_1, x, pdfNormal_2, x, pdfNormal_3);
plot(x,pdfNormal_1,'-')
plot(x,pdfNormal_2,':')
plot(x,pdfNormal_3,'--')
```

But it doesnt work. Could someone give a little help? Regards

Comment: use `hold on` or `hold all`.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your comment while writing my answer.

Comment: Could you tell me how to paint all lines in black? I removed the % but is gives me error.

Comment: Do you mean the lines from `plot(x,pdfNormal_1,'-')`? Simply use `k-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you entered `hold off` before, you need `hold on` after the first plot. Otherwise, your plots will be replaced.

```
plot(x,pdfNormal_1,'-'); hold on;
plot(x,pdfNormal_2,':')
plot(x,pdfNormal_3,'--')
```